# Don't working key listener on compiled exe

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pynput

I hide programm in tray with Qt.Key:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.hide()
```

And activate keyboard listener for show window after her minimized with 'end' key.

```
class InactiveHotKey(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

        def on_release(key):
            if key == Key.end:
                w.showNormal()
                return False

        with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

in Pycharm everything work, but after compile programm with pyinstaller(--onefile --icon=main_icon.ico --noconsole main.py) 'w.showNormal()' don't working.

Comment: Not working how, exactly?

Comment: After press key programm still hide. But still working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem resolved. I forgot install pynput on main python environment, it worked only in project venv.

Comment: Using an import like that can lead to unexpected problems like yours; you should probably put it at the beginning as usual, but within a `try/except` and eventually start the key listener only if the import was successful.